# recover disk files after accidently changed disk partition table

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I changed my external hard disk partition table for installing windows and I didn't know that it will clean all of data

now I lost about 100 GB of my data and don't know how to recover them

used GParted for this

Comment: Windows is usually quite nasty if you try to install it on an external drive.  Will let my betters post about recovering data, but do not use external for now.  Be best to disconnect it safely.

Comment: If not rebooted recover partition:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10364557&postcount=34 Various tools: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery Many use this:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk, if deeper search shows files, immediately copy them as you may not get to them again. With any major system change you must make sure you backups are current.

Comment: can I recover data without partition table or I need a table to do this ?